# Magento - Get custom form field value from product page

Tags: php, forms, magento

I have a Magento shop in which my client wants to sell personalized gift items. For example a pencil with the customer's girlfriend name.

In the product page i managed to show in the form `product_addtocart_form` some fields like this one:

`<input type="text" value="" id="gift_name" name="gift_name">`

Now I have an observer that when the user does the checkout (`checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`) it should get that custom field value but I can't figure out how.

I tried something like `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('gift_name');` but didn't work out.

I think that this parameter is being passed to the form just like the quantity, but how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to get parameter from url in your observer function

```
$request    = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
    $parameter  = $request->yourparametername;
```

Comment: Hi Zaheerabbas, unfortunately it is not working
`$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();`
`$gift_name = $request->gift_name;`

This is making my cart cycle on and on without going with the order. Doesn't your solution have something to do with url parameters which i have none?

Comment: just print parameter array like print_r($request->getParams()) and see what's the output.have you get any parameter in array or not?

Comment: Not printing anything, i guess the error is in the `$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();` because if I replace that with `$request = 'test'` it is printing "test".

To be clear, I have no url parameters, I would like to get that <input> value just like as the system gets the quantity, rough and rude :) any other solutions out there?

Comment: Ohhh then you can use something like for getting GET or POST value
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();,Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('myargument');`